# Implementation for Alin Tomescu's Aggregatable Subvector Commitments for Stateless Cryptocurrencies

Tags: cryptography, state

I’m a cryptography researcher attempting to understand the problem of statelessness.

I came across this paper by Alin Tomescu, et al titled “Aggregatable Subvector Commitments for Stateless Cryptocurrencies”.

Does anyone know if there is an implementation of this?

Many thanks